# Node js .ejs files main index

Tags: node.js, ejs

I followed this tutorial on [sctoch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) to use ejs files but I'm looking for a main index to include the current page.

In the tutorial we will add head, header and footer inside all news pages.

But I want to write this once. For example :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>
<body class="container">

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <main>
        <!-- Here is that I want -->
        <% include ../partials/main %>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do load the good page inside the main file when I clic on different link of my navbar ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to use Express and his template engine(views),so just add header and footer in every new file  you make

```
<% include header %>

 <!-- yout html code -->

<% include footer %>
```

And when you render it simply say

```
res.render('YourNewFile');
```

Your header should look something like this..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title><%- title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

And footer ..just close all tags ..and load some scripts if u want in it

```
<script src="..."></script>
</body>
</html>
```